# Understanding the Purpose of the input_variables Parameter in LangChain's PromptTemplate?

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

I came across a confusion while reading the [LangChain documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/prompts/prompt_templates/) regarding the `input_variables` parameter. The documentation states:

> For additional validation, specify input_variables explicitly. These variables will be compared against the variables present in the template string during instantiation.

However, when I attempt to write a prompt like this:

```py
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

invalid_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    "Tell me a {adjective} joke about {content}."
)
```

I explicitly know the variables are `adjective` and `content`, so I don't understand the benefit of the input_variables parameter. Could you explain the purpose of this parameter and how to use it in the context of my provided example? Additionally, if possible, provide some examples of how to correctly configure input_variables. Thanks for your help!

Perhaps it is used when the template is a variable? For example, like this:

```py
possible_prompt = PromptTemplate(
   input_variables=["adjective"],
   template= template #tempalte from somewhere else
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`PromptTemplate` produces the final prompt that will be sent to the language model. This syntax

```
"Tell me a {adjective} joke about {content}."
```

is similar to a string template. it allows us to pass dynamic values. when you run the chain, you specify the values for those templates. For example let's say you defined `call_chain` function

```
def call_chain(args)
    # create llm, prompt template, chain
    # finally call the chain
    chain({
        "adjective":args.adjective,
        "content":args.content
})
```